# Some hint on this question, prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory

for all prime number $x,y,z$, $x^2 + y^2 \ne z^2$.

I assume $x^2+y^2 = z^2$, then $x^2 = z^2 - y^2$, so we have $x^2 = (z+y)(z-y)$ but I don't know how to continue because I don't know any number theory theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $z - y$ cannot be $1$ unless $z=3,y=2$. But you can rule out that case. Thus $(z+y)$ and $(z-y)$ are both non-trivial factors of $x^2$, and hence they both have prime divisors which are non-trivial factors of $x$.

Comment: how do I shouw that $z-y \ne 1 ?$ and why does that $(z+y),(z-y)$ are non-trivial factors of $x^2$ implies both have prime divisors which are non-trivial factors of $x$ ?. can be more specific?

Comment: @Sophia Hua If $z-y=1$ then either z or y is even.

Comment: $x - y \neq 1$ unless $x = 3, y = 2$ because any two different prime numbers are at least $2$ apart because for any two consecutive integers $z,z+1$, where $z \geq 2$, either $z$ or $z+1$ is divisible by $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y,z)=(p,q,r)$, which is more common notation for prime numbers.

Assume the opposite holds, i.e. exist $p,q,r\in\mathbb P$ s.t. $$p^2=r^2-q^2=(r+q)(r-q)$$

$r>q$ and so $r-q>0$.

---

If $r-q=1$, then exactly one of $r,q$ must be even, since the difference of two numbers of the same parity is always even, but $1$ isn't even.
Exactly one of $r,q$ must be even (equal to $2$) and it must be $q$, since $r>q$ and it is impossible to have $2>q$ and $q$ prime.

$r-2=1\iff r=3$ and so $(r,q)=(3,2)$. But then $p^2=5$, impossible.

---

So $r-q>1$ and clearly $r+q>1$. The only divisors of $p^2$ are $1,p,p^2$, but $r-q,r+q$ both divide $p^2$ and both are larger than $1$, so $r-q=p, r+q=p$, which implies $q=0$, impossible.

Comment: oh, thanks, i got

Answer (score 0):

Before we deal with the prime numbers, we need to establish the following:

For $p>0$,  $p^2+4<p^2+4p+4$

Thus $p^2+4<(p+2)^2$

Consider $p^2+4=q^2$

It must be that $q^2<(p+2)^2$

and hence $q<p+2$.

We have established that if $p^2+4=q^2$, then $q<p+2$.

Now to your problem.

We know that $(Odd)^2=Odd$ and $(Even)^2=Even$.

We know that $Odd + Odd = Even$, that $Even + Even = Even$ and that $Odd+Even=Odd$.

If $x$ and $y$ are both odd, then $z$ is even. The only even prime is 2.

So $x^2+y^2=4$

We can establish by exhaustion that the only integer roots to this equation are $(x,y)=(2,0)$ and $(x,y)=(0,2)$, but these do not satisfy the requirement for both $x$ and $y$ to be prime.

If $x$ and $y$ are both even, then $z$ is even. The only even prime is 2.

That would mean that $(x,y,z)=(2,2,2)$ but $2^2+2^2 >2^2$.

Suppose just one of $x$ or $y$ is even. Without loss of generalisation, let $y$ be even. So $y=2$.

Then $x^2+2^2=z^2$

$x^2+4=z^2$

From earlier, we know that this means that $z<x+2$.

But this is not possible as $z$ and $x$ are odd primes (integers) with a minimum difference of 2.